How much current is consumed when driving the base of the BJT in this circuit?
How much current is consumed from 1.2V when the base is driven? How do I make sure this current is below 90mA? Do I need to change the design?


Welcome! What’s the forward voltage of a BE? What limits the current going into it? Answer these questions and you have helped yourself forward towards the answer.

VBe is minimum 0.65V, and that was supposed to be 90nA. The 1v2 supply can source upto 1A.

And what's the equation for the current though a circuit with a 0.65 V diode (or LED of that help you visualize/internalize it), a resistor and a voltage source?


How do I make sure this [base] current is below 90mA?

By testing a real circuit on a breadboard - should take a couple minutes at most.
Or via a thought experiment. Replace the B-E junction with a short, and see what current flows then, as the entire 1.2V is dropped across the resistor (below, right). A real transistor will have a non-zero voltage across the B-E junction, thus less voltage will be dropped across R1, and a lower current will flow through R1 (below, left).

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
So, about 0.06mA will flow through the base, varying with temperature a bit. In the limiting case it will be 0.12mA if the B-E junction was shorted. But it won't be.
So, you're way, way below 90mA of base current. All is good.

Nice circuit story...

Without even considering the transistor, first ask yourself what kind of voltage must you apply across a 10kΩ resistor, in order to get 90mA through it? The answer comes from Ohm's law, of course:
$$ V = I \times R = 90mA \times 10k\Omega = 900V $$
You don't have anywhere near 900V across that resistor, so you're definitely under the 90mA limit.

Good approach...
